# Flash - Adding movieclip into loader

Tags: flash, loader, movieclip, stage

i have created a preloader for my swf file. I want to simply add an image onto the stage whilst another swf is loading.

My image is saved in a movieclip called image in the library. How would i add it to the stage and make it stay there whilst it is being loaded. I have tried manually moving it onto the stage but it only stays for 1 frame.

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.text.*;

var myContent:URLRequest = new URLRequest("flashheader.swf");
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();

myLoader.load(myContent);

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, preLoader);
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);


function preLoader(event:ProgressEvent):void 
{    
var loaded:Number = Math.round(event.bytesLoaded);
var total:Number = Math.round(event.bytesTotal);
var percent:Number = loaded/total*100;

 percentText.text = Math.round(percent) + "%"


}

function loadComplete(event:Event):void
{
   addChild(myLoader);
   removeChild(percentText);
```

}

Thanks,

DIM3NSION

Answer (score 0):

The reason it stays only for one frame is probably because the stage (your main timeline) has several frames on it, so it just zips by.

Try adding a stop(); at the top of this code if this is actionscript on the **first frame** on the timeline.

In any case, you need to place a stop() to prevent the stage from automatically progressing to the next frame of the timeline.

See whether this fixes it for you or ask for clarifications please.

Edit: OK, you said it's flashing every now and again, so you have more then 1 frame in one in your movieclips 100% sure. Especially if you added the stop(). Make sure all movieclips have exatcly 1 frame, not just the stage, it has to be that if this is the whole code you have and you see it flashing (the movieclip for that image has to be looping or something).

Comment: hmm no other frames. added a stop but still with no luck. For some reason it just flashes up every now and again? All i have is that code there. a text box on the one frame that has an instance of percentText then i have a movieclip of image in the library

Comment: If you are testing this on your hard disk (inside your IDE), that load would take roughly one frame to complete, the hard disks are generally fast enough. If you tried to load this somewhere from the net, you would probably see it slower. Are you testing this from inside the flash IDE? If you are, try uploading  those files to your hosting if you have one.

Comment: And this code is on the stage, on the first frame? the same as the image you dragged to the stage in that mc(1 frame again)? Can you make sure everything has just one frame, and also you can place trace("finished"); inside loadComplete function to see when exactly the load finishes. Try it please.